# How to target specific img using css

Tags: html, css

All,

I know there have been some posts about this issue but the suggestions dont seem to work. What am I doing wrong here?

This is the snippet. The first part in my `css` that is not commented out will apply the opacity to my two images on hover.

When removing the first block and commenting in the second block, its suppose to target only the delta.jpg image and apply the opacity, leaving the shh.png image to be unaffected.

```css
.wsite-image-border-none img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/*
.wsite-image-border-none img[src="image\delta.jpg"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="wsite-image wsite-image-border-none " style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-left:0;margin-right:0">
 <a><img src="image\shh.png" alt="Picture" style="width:293;max-width:100%"></a>
 <a><img src="image\delta.jpg" alt="Picture" style="width:293; max-width:100%"></a>
 <div style="display:block;font-size:90%"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to do this on my weebly site where I don't have 100% control over the HTML. Need to do this in CSS.

Thanks

Comment: try using forward slash `/` as in `image/delta.jpg` instead of backslashes ` \ ` as a start. Backslash is used for escaping characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\` character has special meaning; it is used to [escape characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#escaping0).

If you want to match a single `\` character, you will need to use two of them `\\`:

```
.wsite-image-border-none img[src="image\\delta.jpg"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```css
img[src="image\\delta.jpg"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<img src="image\delta.jpg" />
```

---

However, as pointed out in the comments, since paths typically use forward slashes, you may actually want:

```
.wsite-image-border-non img[src="image/delta.jpg"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```css
img[src="image/delta.jpg"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<img src="image/delta.jpg" />
```

Comment: Not to mention, web paths typically use forward slashes

Comment: Thanks that worked for my example. woud you be able to look at the real site? http://shopdowntowndogstampa.weebly.com. There is a green img that says "Show Now" and this is the css I have in place      .wsite-image-border-none img[src="/uploads/5/6/6/2/56620167/218291.png?293"] :hover{
  opacity: 0.5;
}

Comment: @J.Pyz Remove the space between `[src ...]` and `:hover` -> `.wsite-image-border-none img[src="/uploads/5/6/6/2/56620167/218291.png?293"]:hover`

Comment: thanks @joshcrozier unfortunately that didn't do it. Im wondering if its an issue with weebly's image file path since these suggestions seem to work on my own html example

Answer (score 0):

You could use nth-of-type selector in css to be more specific.

```
.wsite-image-border-none a:nth-of-type(2) img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps. You can also try inserting images in a separate div and styling that image.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.